# Change game difficulty - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm in the middle of making a hangman game with javascript. I'm now trying to make it more complex by adding the possibility of changing the game difficulty. I've tested a few different ways and tried to google how to do it, but none of my attempts seem to work so far. In my latest attempt I've tried to create a function that will push to an empty array different arrays of possible words to guess, depending on the difficulty chosen. As a newbie, it looks to me like it should work, but as it is not, I hope someone can explain where I'm going wrong, or if my reasoning is completely wrong to begin with!

Here is the relevant code.

HTML:

```
<button id="easy" onclick="changeDifficulty(1)">Easy</button>
<button id="medium" onclick="changeDifficulty(2)">Medium</button>
<button id="hard" onclick="changeDifficulty(3)">Hard</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Variables
let level = 0;
let randomWords = [];
let easyWords = ['apple', 'gene'];
let mediumWords = ['article', 'trident'];
let hardWords = ['aposthrophe', 'justification'];

// Select game difficulty and push correct array 
function changeDifficulty(difficulty) {
    level = difficulty
    if (level === 0) {
        randomWords.concat(mediumWords)
    } else if (level === 1) {
        randomWords.concat(easyWords)
    } else if (level === 2) {
        randomWords.concat(mediumWords)
    } else if (level === 3){
        randomWords.concat(hardWords)
    }
}

// Generate random word
function getWord() {
    answer = randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomWords.length)]
}

// Call functions
changeDifficulty();
getWord();
```

I then get an error in the inspector regarding another function

```
function guessedWord() {
wordStatus = answer.split('').map(letter => (guessed.indexOf(letter) >= 0 ? letter : '_')).join('');

document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = wordStatus;}
```

saying that "cannot read property split of undefined", so answer is not defined which should be because my previous code is not working.

Any advice on how to fix my code or on a better way to approach changing the difficulty?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for `.concat`: "This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator to make things a bit easyier. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  
  <script>
    // Variables
let level = 0;
let randomWords = [];
let easyWords = ['apple', 'gene'];
let mediumWords = ['article', 'trident'];
let hardWords = ['aposthrophe', 'justification'];

// Select game difficulty and push correct array 
function changeDifficulty(difficulty = 0) {
  
    level = difficulty
    randomWords = []; // if you remove this, your array gets bigger and bigger
    
    if (level === 0) {
        randomWords.push(...mediumWords)
    } else if (level === 1) {
        randomWords.push(...easyWords)
    } else if (level === 2) {
        randomWords.push(...mediumWords)
    } else if (level === 3){
        randomWords.push(...hardWords)
    }
  
  // lets see what our words are
  console.log(randomWords);
  
  getWord();
  
}

// Generate random word
function getWord() {
    let answer = randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomWords.length)]
    console.log(answer);
}

// Call functions
changeDifficulty();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  
<button id="easy" onclick="changeDifficulty(1)">Easy</button>
<button id="medium" onclick="changeDifficulty(2)">Medium</button>
<button id="hard" onclick="changeDifficulty(3)">Hard</button>

</body>
</html>
```

With the spread operator you can combine diffrent levels, if you do something like that:

```js
    if (level === 0) {
        randomWords.push(...mediumWords)
    } else if (level === 1) {
        randomWords.push(...easyWords)
    } else if (level === 2) {
        randomWords.push(...mediumWords, ...easyWords)
    } else if (level === 3){
        randomWords.push(...hardWords, ...mediumWords)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to reassign your arrays :

```
if (level === 0) {
    randomWords = randomWords.concat(mediumWords)
}
```

But BTW, it is useless to use concat in this context, directly assign your array instead

```
if (level === 0) {
    randomWords = mediumWords
}
```

Edit :
I suggest you to think a different logic to be the more flexible as possible, like so :

```
let level = "";
let randomWords = [];
let dictionary = {
  easy: ['apple', 'gene'],
  medium: ['article', 'trident'],
  hard: ['aposthrophe', 'justification']
}


function changeDifficulty(difficulty) {
    level = difficulty
    randomWords = dictionary[level]
}
```

And your buttons :

```
<button id="easy" onclick="changeDifficulty('easy')">Easy</button>
<button id="medium" onclick="changeDifficulty('medium')">Medium</button>
<button id="hard" onclick="changeDifficulty('hard')">Hard</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Modified your JS a little and it now generates a random word from each array depending on difficulty chosen

JS

```
// Variables
let randomWords = [];
let easyWords = ['apple', 'gene'];
let mediumWords = ['article', 'trident'];
let hardWords = ['aposthrophe', 'justification'];

// Select game difficulty and push correct array 
function changeDifficulty(difficulty) {
  // no need to use the variable level
    if (difficulty === undefined || difficulty === 2) { // Calling array without passing argument passes in undefined so by default its set to choose medium words
        randomWords = mediumWords.slice()
    } else if (difficulty === 1) {
        randomWords = easyWords.slice()
    } else if (difficulty === 3){
        randomWords = hardWords.slice()
    }
  console.log(randomWords)
}

// Generate random word
function getWord() {
  answer = randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomWords.length)]
}

// Call functions
changeDifficulty();
getWord();
```

HTML

```
<button id="easy" onclick="changeDifficulty(1)">Easy</button>
<button id="medium" onclick="changeDifficulty(2)">Medium</button>
<button id="hard" onclick="changeDifficulty(3)">Hard</button>
<button id="newword" onclick="getWord()">New Word</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable **answer** first

```js
let answer = "";
```

your method changeDifficulty is not correct since it does not set the value to your randomWords, you need to do so

```js
function changeDifficulty(difficulty) {
    level = difficulty
    if (level === 0) {
        randomWords = randomWords.concat(mediumWords)
    } else if (level === 1) {
        randomWords = randomWords.concat(easyWords)
    } else if (level === 2) {
        randomWords = randomWords.concat(mediumWords)
    } else if (level === 3){
        randomWords = randomWords.concat(hardWords)
    }
}
```

and to get your **answer** correctly you should call the getWord after each button click (or somewhere else in your logic).
(https://jsfiddle.net/4a9sjhcq/)